# Coming to stay in u.s.if you have proof of a place to stay do you still need proof of funds

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, proof-of-funds, proof-of-accommodation

If coming to the u.s to stay if they provide proof that they have a place to live and someone who will provide till they are working do they still havr to have proof of funds on them .she is coming from uk

Comment: Stay for how long? What visa are we talking about?

Comment: We are to be married when she gets here ihave been to the uk to see her and now shes coming here her passport is up to date but i am wondering about the amount of funds she needs on hand .will a noterized letter work or what do i need to do she will have 500$

Comment: Add this information to your question.